# mongodb: enable textSearch

Tags: mongodb

I'll see in other answered question that for enable beta feature of textserch in MongoDb i must activate the option in the config file. My question is where and with which command?

That's because i didn't have that parameter in my mongodb.conf file so i suppose i need to add all the line.
Which is the correct syntax from these two?

```
#textSearchEnabled=true
```

or

```
#setParameter=textSearchEnabled=true
```

it's not important where to place the command?

thanks all

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several options for enabling the beta text search feature in MongoDB 2.4:

- in your MongoDB configuration file with:

  > setParameter=textSearchEnabled=true
- via the command-line when you start `mongod`:

  `mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true`
- via the `mongo` shell:

  > db.adminCommand( { setParameter: true, textSearchEnabled : true})

Setting via a config file is typically the preferred option, so you don't have to remember to re-enable this when you restart your MongoDB.

In the upcoming MongoDB 2.6 release the text search feature will be [enabled by default](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10913) and the above options will be deprecated (and unnecessary).