# Set text search feature in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, production-environment, mongohq

I have a production server hosted in mongohq with version 2.4.6.
I need to add text index to one of the collections.
I tried using the below command from mongo client connecting to my remote server:

> db.logs.ensureIndex({title: 'text', description: 'text'})

By default, we cannot add index to production server, since it is restricted by mongohq.
But I need to restart the server like below to enable text search:

> mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true

But this is possible only for local servers.

Does anyone know how to get this done on remote mongohq server?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in mongoclient "mongo", it should work for you

```
db.adminCommand( { setParameter : 1, textSearchEnabled : true } )
```

also check out these links, they may be helpful

http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/enable-text-search/

[mongodb: enable textSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668820/mongodb-enable-textsearch)

Comment: I have added some links checkout if they can be a help to you.

Comment: The first link was helpful since it says not to enable text-search on production. But still need to know the reason. Thank you.